# Any advantage of creating table in temporary tablespace - Oracle

Tags: oracle, tablespaces

My on-site DBA told me to create the particular table on temporary tablespace.Is there any advantage of such action?

Comment: Not sure if tha'ts the same thing, but i.e. creating a global temporary table does not generate any redo or rollback information. If the data table you are creating does not need to be persistent, that's probably why your DBA told you to do that.

Comment: A temporary *tablespace* is used by Oracle as scratch space for sorts that don't fit into memory, you cannot create a table there. A temporary *table* is a table whose rows are not kept when a transaction ends or when you logout. Either you misheard or your DBA is confused.

Comment: You can. create table example (example number) tablespace TEMP;

Comment: Have to correct myself here. You can create a table that is intent on using a certain tablespace, but can't add anything. (Only then actual segments are created).

Answer (score 2):

I believe your DBA told you to use temporary tablespace for temporary data? If so using temporary tables have the following advantages:

- DML on temporary tables does not generate redo. If one uses direct path INSERT (INSERT /*+ append */, CTAS) then undo is also not generated. On 12c it is possible to store UNDO in temporary tablespace as well!
- after session crash Oracle will take care to remove your data
- after instance crash temporary tables do not require recover

Of course I forgot something. :) People will add more advantages in comments.

While listing advantages I am not considering scenario when you have to preserve data between restarts.

[Database Concepts about Temporary Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#CBBBADBI)

Comment: There is a difference between "Global Temporary Tables" and "Temporary tablespaces using temporary datafiles". Your answer is unclear on what you're talking about, although i think most of the statements will be true for both.